# Strange behavior of obtained backtrace, passed variable value getting changed at the receiver method, evident from the backtrace obtained

Tags: c, gdb, stack-trace, callstack, backtrace

I am facing a strange behavior by the program when debugging using gdb. Below mentioned is the backtrace of my program from the core. I am seeing a strange behavior when I traverse the program from frame 4 to frame 3 (#4 to #3).

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb76b5a29 in memset ()
#1  0xb786e916 in calloc (mem=429496, size=8)
#2  0xb788db57 in fetch_vals (bt_ptr=0x818776c, num_bt=135831740, txn=0xb24dd750)
#3  0xb788ffe2 in build_list (pol_id=0, txn=0xb24dd750)
#4  0xb788bc7f in request (fields=0xb5320c90, attrs=0x0)
#5  0xb789c214 in process_ipc (fd_info=0x80cff9c, msg=0xb5320c60, opq=0xb249bfd0)
#6  0xb77acd04 in process_recv (fd_info=0x80cff9c, arg=0x0, flags=0)
#7  0xb77a7385 in main (arg=0x8070db4)
#8  0xb76451e8 in __pthread_initialize ()
#9  0xb770172a in clone ()
```

Variable **pol_id** passed to **build_list()** method is a local variable defined inside **request()** method. I am not modifying this variable anywhere in the calling or called method. However, while looking at the backtrace, I found out that its value is getting cleared to 0 sometimes due to which the program fails. This is evident if I look at #3 where its received as 0 (**build_list(pol_id=0, txn=0xb24dd750)** ).

Mentioned below is the "info local" for frame 4 of stack(***request()***), where we can see that the value of **pol_id = 2**.

```
(gdb) f 4
#4  0xb788bc7f in request (fields=0xb5320c90, attrs=0x0)
274         req = build_list(pol_id, &txn);
(gdb) info local
req = (request *) 0x1
resp = (response *) 0x0
txn = {pol_set_id = 2, flags = 0, fields = 0xb5320c90}
pol_id = 2
__FUNCTION__ = "request"
(gdb)
```

Can anyone please point me out why this could be happening? I checked my program and there is no modification of pol_id variable.

Thanks.

Comment: The most common reason would be buffer overrun on a nearby variable.

Comment: Some source code might be helpful.

Comment: Did you build your program with optimization enabled? If so, the debugger may simply be confused.

Comment: Your application somehow smashed its stack after having entered `build_list()`. Form the function's name I conclude you are are messing around with dynamical allocated memory and references to it, so such thing can easily happen ... ;-)

Comment: I had 2 threads, one thread freed a linked list and another one accidently started accessing that which lead me to this situation. I had different backtraces and this one particularly confused me. However, linked list was using memory from heap and local variables are in stack, so I am not sure how I could endup with buffer overrun on a nearby variable.